# selinium works when called directly from shell but not as part of a script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the following code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Works perfectly when I execute it line after line in the shell (with ipython) but fails on creating the driver when executed as a script in a .py file.

Any idea why?

Here is the ipython info:

> stof@grice:~$ ipython Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)|
>   (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)  Type "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.

and the exception stack is:

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: can you copy and paste the traceback instead of the image? it's tru

Comment: I tried. For some reason it wouldn't let me paste the exceptions stack. It keeps on giving me the "seems like an inappropriately indented code" err msg, no matter what I do.